# How to create a property file from jenkins scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am creating a property block or a map which is given below and I want to write it to a file. I couldn't find a way to writeProperties to a file from a pipeline code. Need help on figuring out on how to do it.

```
def props = [APPNAME = 'testaoo',
            DEPLOY_ENV = stream,
            DEPLOY_STREAM = stream_num,
            DEPLOY_ENV_TYPE = deploy_env_type,
            BUILD_JOB_ID = env.BUILD_JOB_ID,
            WAS_NDM_AgentURL= getAgentURL(stream),
            WAS_CLUSTER = getClusterName(stream),
            DeployPublishNeeded = 'Yes'
            ]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
def props = [
    APPNAME : 'testaoo',
    DeployPublishNeeded : 'Yes'
]

def content = props.collect{entry->entry.key+"="+entry.value}.join('\n')

writeFile file: 'a.properties', text: content
```